# multi label classification to different text

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

Assuming that I have different keyword that labelled to different content.
such as

```
    label                                      content
    great, amazing                            our company is bla bla
                                              bla bla bla......

    amazing, horrible,interesting              our company is bla bla
                                              bla bla bla......

    boring                                    our company is bla bla
                                              bla bla bla......
```

Then, I wanna use classification machine learning model to build a model.

Could any one teach me how to make this kind of multi label classification work and build?

p.s. I prefer to use scikit-learn library

Comment: Check the examples here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification-format

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have read this before I post this question. However, it seems always to be overfitting. It is because the example provided by sklearn is just going for some simple text, such as one sentence. However, the text now I have is talking about a huge number of work rather than just one sentence.

Actually, I have read though the example in kaggle. (https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words) It is near what I want ,but when I tried to but it into the a multi label classification, it seems fall into overfitting easily.

Will anyone share me his idea of text mining question?